# Use ServiceWorker cache only when offline

Tags: javascript, browser-cache, web-worker, service-worker

I'm trying to integrate service workers into my app, but I've found the service worker tries to retrieve cached content even when online, but I want it to prefer the network in these situations. How can I do this? Below is the code I have now, but I don't believe it is working. SW Install code is omitted for brevity.

```
var CACHE_NAME = 'my-cache-v1';
var urlsToCache = [
  /* my cached file list */
];

self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
  // Perform install steps
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(CACHE_NAME)
      .then(function(cache) {
        console.log('Opened cache');
        return cache.addAll(urlsToCache);
      })
  );
});

/* request is being made */
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  event.respondWith(
    //first try to run the request normally
    fetch(event.request).catch(function() {
      //catch errors by attempting to match in cache
      return caches.match(event.request).then(function(response) {
        // Cache hit - return response
        if (response) {
          return response;
        }
      });
    })
  );
});
```

This seems to lead to warnings like `The FetchEvent for "[url]" resulted in a network error response: an object that was not a Response was passed to respondWith().` I'm new to service workers, so apologies for any mistaken terminology or bad practices, would welcome any tips. Thank you!

Comment: Do the warnings only occur while offline?  Its possible you are getting requests for unexpected URLs, like favicons, that are not stored in your cache install event.

Comment: This happened when online, when offline the service worker actually seems to work as expected.

Comment: EDIT: I also get these errors when offline, but you're right, only for resources I don't have stored in cache.

Comment: @RubenMartinezJr. did you manage to figure this out? I'm getting the same issue on my Rails setup. Very weird.

Comment: I didn't really :/ I switched to using Google's [SW-Toolbox](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/sw-toolbox) instead, it's a much nicer API!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Without testing this out, my guess is that you're not resolving `respondWith()` correctly in the case where there is no cache match. [According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FetchEvent/respondWith), the code passed to `respondWith()` is supposed to "resolve by returning a Response or network error to Fetch." So why not try just doing this:

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  event.respondWith(
    fetch(event.request).catch(function() {
      return caches.match(event.request);
    })
  );
});
```

Comment: Also see Jake's offline-cookbook: https://jakearchibald.com/2014/offline-cookbook/#network-falling-back-to-cache

Comment: This code is essentially the same as what I have above, and unfortunately results in the same errors :/

Comment: Given that this seems to be the documented method, I'm going to accept this and assume there's something fishy going on somewhere...Will update if I discover more.

Comment: Just a thought, but are your sure the file name/url is correct? I'm testing something similar and it appears that the catch is not reached and then you get an undefined response object which causes this error.

Comment: Another quick thought: Since you're getting the `respondWith` warning, it means the `caches.match()` isn't finding that resource. Could be as simple as a query string or trailing slash.

Comment: That won't work in case of a cache miss (which returns undefined). You always need to return a Response which can be synthetic.

Answer (score 6):

Why don't you open the cache for your fetch event?
I think the process of a service worker is :

- Open your cache
- Check if the request match with an answer in your cache
- Then you answer

OR (if the answer is not in the cache) :

- Check the request via the network
- Clone your answer from the network
- Put the request and the clone of the answer in your cache for future use

I would write :

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  event.respondWith(
    caches.open(CACHE_NAME).then(cache => {
     return cache.match(event.request).then(response => {
      return response || fetch(event.request)
      .then(response => {
        const responseClone = response.clone();
        cache.put(event.request, responseClone);
        })
      })
    }
 );
});
```

Answer (score 5):

[event.respondWith() expects a promise that resolves to Response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FetchEvent/respondWith). So in case of a cache miss, you still need to return a Response, but above, you are returning nothing. I'd also try to use the cache first, then fetch, but in any case, as the last resort, you can always create a synthetic Response, for example something like this:

```
return new Response("Network error happened", {"status" : 408, "headers" : {"Content-Type" : "text/plain"}});
```